# Dynamically access dictionary element stored as string in a variable

Tags: c#, dictionary, reflection

Is there a way to access dictionary element dynamically when the element name is stored as a string in a variable?

```
string field2 = "Entity[\"EmpId\"]";
```

I have tried accessing the string type and it works as expected but not able to understand how to get the dictionary element value dynamically. Here is what I tried so far. [Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2kYwCZ)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.EntityId = "123456";

        message.Entity = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
        {
            { "EmpId", "987654"},
            { "DeptId", "10"}
        };

        // Dynamically accessing the field WORKS
        string field1 = "EntityId";
        var v1 = message.GetType().GetProperty(field1).GetValue(message, null); // <-- Works as expected
        Console.WriteLine("EntityId: " + v1.ToString());  // <-- Output: 123456

        // Dynamically accessing a Dictionary element DOESN'T WORK
        string field2 = "Entity[\"EmpId\"]";
        var v2 = message.GetType().GetProperty(field2).GetValue(message, null); // <-- Throws an exception
        //Console.WriteLine("Name: " + v2.ToString());  // <-- Expected Outut: 987654

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    class Message
    {
        public string EntityId { get; set; }

        // Replacing EntityId with a Dictionary as we have more than one Entities
        public Dictionary<string, string> Entity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing it wrong. Do the following

```
string field2 = "Entity";
var v2 = message.GetType().GetProperty(field2).GetValue(message, null) as Dictionary<string, string>;

Console.WriteLine("Name: " + v2["EmpId"]);  // Outut: 987654
```

Comment: OP asked for **Dynamically accessing** a Dictionary element. You did it directly.

Comment: Not sure if cast is not desired since it already says its gonna be a Dictionary.

Comment: It almost seem like OP wanted to access the object through xml selector, which is not gonna work without some magic trick.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is not XML, you have to work through it layer by layer :

```
// First, get the Entity property, and invoke the getter
var entity = message.GetType().GetProperty("Entity").GetValue(message);
// Second, get the indexer property on it, and invoke the getter with an index(key)
var empId = entity.GetType().GetProperty("Item").GetValue(entity, new[] { "EmpId" });

Console.WriteLine("Name: " + empId);
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
//string field2 = "Entity[\"EmpId\"]";
 string f2="Entity";string key="EmpId";
 var v2 =((Dictionary<string,string>)message.GetType().GetProperty(f2).GetValue(message, null))[key];
```

You can see it working at here https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=fc89qQ#code-editor